# react hooks: Pass a state setter as an argument to an async function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state-management

Tl;Dr - Can I pass a `useState` setter to as an argument to an `async` function? The async function would make a request and then on a success, store the response using the state setter.

Demonstration

```
const getResource = async (setResponse) => {
 const apiResponse = await axios.get(<Some_URL>)
 if (apiResponse) {
   setResponse(apiResponse)
  }
}

SomePage = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
     getResource(setResponse)
}, [])

return (
  { response && <SomeComponent data={response}/> }
)}
```

In the react hooks documentation I noticed something similar where they passed a setter to a seemingly async function `ChatApi.SubsrcibeToSomething(..., setter)` so thats why I am asking. I want to understand if this is an acceptable practice or if I might be missing something here where behavior might get wonky. I am new to react please bear with me - appreciate any tips/best practices for handling request/response as well as how to store responses to state (react hooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you? Yes, you absolutely can do that. It's valid syntax. Should you though? Now this can be a little subjective.

Your implementation:

```
const getResource = async (setResponse) => {
  const apiResponse = await axios.get(<Some_URL>)
  if (apiResponse) {
    setResponse(apiResponse);
  }
};

const SomePage = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getResource(setResponse);
  }, []);

  return response ? <SomeComponent data={response}/> : null'
};
```

This is akin to passing a success callback. This should be familiar if you've used Promise-based APIs where you call a function and pass a success and failure callback.

Example: `asynchronousCall(onSuccess, onFailure)` or even simply `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { .... });`

The benefit here is that the API is simple for the component providing the callback.

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  getResource(setResponse); // <-- just pass the setter
}, []);
```

The con to this is that the component owning the `response` state has effectively off-loaded the responsibility for external code to maintain any state invariants, i.e. the "3rd-party" code needs to know what and how to call the callback and what to pass it. In a lot of cases you write both parts and can make it work. Sometimes that is not the case though.

Better to pass a callback that *just* consumes a value and the parent handles updating its internal state.

```
const getResource = async (setResponse) => {
  const apiResponse = await axios.get(<Some_URL>)
  if (apiResponse) {
    setResponse(apiResponse);
  }
};

const SomePage = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const responseHandler = response => {
    // business logic
    setResponse(computedResponseValue);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getResource(responseHandler);
  }, []);

  return response ? <SomeComponent data={response}/> : null'
};
```

The parent component here passes a handler that takes a response value and manages how it wants the state to be updated.

Best to simply return a value back to caller and let them handle it.

```
const getResource = async () => {
  const apiResponse = await axios.get(<Some_URL>)
  return apiResponse;
};

const SomePage = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getResource()
      .then(response => {
        // business logic
        setResponse(computedResponseValue);
      });
  }, []);

  return response ? <SomeComponent data={response}/> : null'
};
```

The benefit now is that `getResource` is simply and only needs to return a resolved value, and the component maintains control over the response handling.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to save the response in the state with a hook.

1. The best practice would be to use the hook in the useEffect. (this is the best option because if the parent decide what to do with the response, the function with the call will be more reusable and "atomic")
2. The second option would be passing the hook in the function which makes the call (that is what you want according the question).

I let you a class that you can copy and paste to test it with the two options implemented.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Question1 = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);

  const getResource = async () => {
    return await axios.get("https://api.publicapis.org/entries")
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(() => ({ count: 0, entries: null}));
  }

  const getResource2 = async (setter) => {
    return await axios.get("https://api.publicapis.org/entries")
      .then(response => {
        setter(response.data);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setter({ count: 0, entries: null})
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    /*
    // Option 1
    getResource().then(data => {
      setResponse(data);
    });
    */
    // Option 2
    getResource2(setResponse);
  }, [])
  return (<div>
    { response && (<div>{response.count}</div>)}
  </div>)
}

export default Question1;
```

I hope I've helped you.

Comment: Definitely. I appreciate the response too btw, this added more clarity to my understanding of react + promises in react